# Body not full width on mobile

Tags: html, css

The body of my website does not span full width when on mobile screen or smaller than approx. 450px. You can see in the screenshot below that my inspector tells me that the width of the body is the same as the width of the screen, but the visuals does not display correctly.

[image]

I have tried to use min-width: 100% and 100vw but that does not seem to be working. When using a real mobile device the content is displayed correctly because of my meta tag, but when scrolling horizontally to the right the body is cut of. This is the meta tag that I use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have tried to delete all the css and the bootstrap that I use, but the problem remains. I therefore think I need some kind of extra css to solve the solution. How can I solve this? I appreciate all help.

You can view the website on this link:
[test.radency.com](http://test.radency.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just realized the problem. A paragraph was too long, stretching the width, but not the body. Adding a word-wrap or just deleting the non-wrapping paragraph solved the problem.